# How to protect access to sensitive files of a laravel application from a sub-application?

Tags: php, laravel, webserver

Can you tell me how to protect access to sensitive files of a laravel application from a sub-application. Currently, the application is a monolith using modules that are sub-sites. The Modules directory is in the root of the application.

How to make it so that from the sub-application it is impossible to read, download files outside Modules without damaging the functionality of the whole application? Or should I use only microservices here?

I need to make it impossible to do something like this from the controller in the module, figuratively:
scandir('/path/to/app/root') or file_get_contents()

Comment: Your modules is the part of application. I think, there is no way to separate them in this manner.